# Comparing tuples to ints

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to make a clock in system that the user inputs a key and it compares it to an sqlite database.

The problem I am having is when comparing the key entered to the one on the database. I am assuming it is because the sqlite query returns a tuple. I thought putting it into a for loop would sort it out. Although they match they come back as false.

```
import sqlite3 as lite

conn = lite.connect('attendance.db')
c = conn.cursor()

r = raw_input('Awaiting Key: ')
keyCode = str(int(r))

q = c.execute("SELECT key FROM employees WHERE key = '%s'") % keyCode

for i in q:
    if i == r:
        print 'open'
    else:
        print 'closed'
```

Comment: That code doesn't make sense, you're trying to `%` format the *value returned by* `c.execute`, not its argument. Also, you shouldn't create SQL queries by string interpolation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't insert data into a query using string interpolation. Query parameters are much more efficient and aren't vulnerable to injection attacks.

```
q = c.execute("SELECT key FROM employees WHERE key = ?", (keyCode,))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
q = c.execute("SELECT key FROM employees WHERE key = '%s'") % keyCode
```

If I'm correct, this is wrong.
You need to do:

```
c.execute("SELECT key FROM employees WHERE key =?",  (keyCode,))
c.fetchone()
```

to return the value you need.

Comment: The percent operator is still on the wrong side of the parentheses, if he's trying to format the string.